# Как вернуть true, если у объекта нет свойств?

Tags: javascript, функции, объекты, bool

Задача:

Напишите функцию `isEmpty`, которая возвращает `true`, если у объекта нет свойств (у самого объекта, не у прототипов), иначе возвращает `false`.

Подскажите, что я делаю не так? По возможности объясните более подробно, как надо сделать и почему это так работает.

Вот моё решение:

```
function isEmpty(obj) {
     for (item in obj) {
      obj.hasOwnProperty(item)
    }
    return false
}
```

Вот тесты, которые должен пройти код. Прошёл только последний тест:

```
✕ должна возвращать true на пустой объект без прототипа (6ms)
✕ должна возвращать true на пустой объект с прототипом (1ms)
✓ должна возвращать false на не пустой объект (2ms)
```

Comment: Начнем с того, что у тебя `true` не возвращается в принципе...

Comment: `Object.keys(obj).length == 0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

должно сработать

```
function isEmpty(obj) {
  for (const key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```